# WKWebView show white screen when loading HTTPS URL of Angular App

Tags: ios, angularjs, swift, webview

apologies for the simple question:

I am following Apple's guide on WKWebView to the dot. Same code and everything.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://amerifit.afvusa.com/MenuMain.aspx?a=NTgzMjEyMTU3")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)

This is the URL I am trying to link to: https://amerifit.afvusa.com/MenuMain.aspx?a=NTgzMjEyMTU3

Except that I am getting a white screen when the viewcontroller tries to load the page.

Any reasons why? The code works fine for Google's homepage and this URL is secure so that isn't the issue.

Also, the website is not mine and I cannot edit it's files.

Comment: I think there is something to do with the https://amerifit instead of https://www. try "https:/ / www.afvusa.com/" and it will work

Comment: I inspected the website to find it is an AngularJS app. could this be the problem? Changing the URL is not really an option